# Making a heatmap for a 1D bar in python

Tags: python

I would like to make a heatmap in python for the heat distribution of a bar made out of points.  Essentially it consists of a bar at some initial temperature between two reservoirs held at a constant temperature.  For example, a bar made of 20 points, each initially at 100C, and 1 point on either side of the bar, both permanently held at 0.

I have made a list of lists showing the diffusion of temperature across the bar as a function of time as such:

[ [0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0] , [0, 75.0, 100.0, 75.0, 0] , [0, 62.5, 87.5, 62.5, 0], [0, 53.125, 75.0, 53.125, 0] ].  Where each list represents the heat distribution in the bar at a certain timestep.

Is there any way to get a heat map of this, where I would have the heat of the bar at different times, stacked on eachother?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses interpolation to smooth the discrete values. If this is not appropriate for your purposes, another idea is trying the heatmap function in the seaborn library. By the way, this considers the ends of your bars as having a unit length equal to 1.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import seaborn as sns #optional
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bars = [ [0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 0], [0, 75.0, 100.0, 75.0, 0], [0, 62.5, 87.5, 62.5, 0], [0, 53.125, 75.0, 53.125, 0] ]

for bar in bars:
    df = pd.DataFrame( (np.array( bar )) )
    ax = plt.subplot( )
    im = ax.imshow( df.transpose( ), cmap=cm.jet, interpolation='nearest', vmin=0, vmax=100 )
    divider = make_axes_locatable( ax )
    cax = divider.append_axes( "right", size="5%", pad=0.05 )
    cb = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
    cb.set_label('Temp deg C')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.NullFormatter())
    plt.show(  )
```

[image: bar1]

[image: bar2]

[image: bar3]

[image: bar4]